# Alternative to using LIMIT clause on MySQL on PHPAdmin

Tags: mysql

I have a database of country club members and their joining date and the assignment is asking me to get the record of the person that joined last. However, it's asking me not to use the LIMIT clause.
I have tried to use the TOP clause but it does not recognize it and I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.
This is what I have

```
SELECT TOP 1 firstname, surname
FROM Members
ORDER BY joindate DESC
```

Comment: `TOP` is SQL-Server syntax. `LIMIT` is the MySQL equivalent.

Comment: `where joindate = (select max(joindate) from...)`. Sometimes an autoincrement ID is better as unique.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MAX(joindate)` to get the most recent date, and match that against the record.

```
SELECT firstname, surname
FROM Members
WHERE joindate = (SELECT MAX(joindate) FROM Members);
```